# How do I cook minced meat faster?

Tags: meat

I know how to cook it fine, with garlic, onions and some seasoning (olives and pepper some times). But the thing is, it takes too long for the water to evaporate (reduce) making it take long.

Is there a way to make it faster?

I'm a very novice "cook", so any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What kind of cookware do you use? The larger the surface area, the faster the evaporation.

Comment: Please also describe what you're doing. Personally, I think I'd throw the onions in first (with some salt and oil), let them sauté for a bit, then add the meat, then in the final seconds add garlic. It sounds like you're adding them all at once, and adding so much (or using too low heat) that your ground meat is being steamed (and overcooked).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also, I would add that I tend to cook in batches, rather than overfilling the pan. So using a large deep skillet put enough in to cover about 2/3 of the base, and cook on high heat til browned etc.

Then I put it into a warmed bowl as I cook the next batch, until I have a full bowl of cooked mince, which I can then put back into the pan to simmer and turn into whatever the end dish is.

Answer (score 7):

Use a large area pan to help the evaporation and use a higher heat with constant stirring to avoid burned meat.

Comment: Answers the question perfectly.

Comment: You can also just carefully tip some of the liquid out of the pan into a suitable receptacle.

Comment: Right you are. Why didn't I think of that?

Comment: What if I don't have a bigger pan? I don't want to use a Wok, it's too big (and clumsy). @ElendilTheTall wouldn't that "waste" some flavor?

Comment: Most of the liquid that comes out of minced meat is greasy water - not a great deal of flavour there.

Comment: @hexa: BaffledCook is probably thinking of a 12" fry pan, larger if your burner can support it. If you don't have a larger one, higher heat will still help (as high as you can go w/o burning) or alternatively I hear there are places that will happily sell you larger pans :-P

Comment: Of course, the constant stirring also prevents a Maillard reaction, resulting in less savoury meat. I tend to just let the meat sit there and just scrape off sticky bits to prevent burning. It’s not as easy (catching the moment just before the meat burns) but it’s worth it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, good point for flavor.